# Why do odyssey.js info bubbles recentre the map?

Tags: carto, infowindow, odyssey-js

I'm using Odyssey.js (scroll) and have created a map with info bubbles when the user clicks on features. On the initial load everything works fine. However, scrolling to the first header means that when I click on a feature the map recentres on somewhere in the Antarctic before showing the info bubble. Has anyone else experienced this problem and is it a known bug within Odyssey?

Here's the map so you can try it for yourself:

http://www.burdgis.com/blog/map/global-palm-oil-production/